# Is it possible to implement such Activity behaviour?

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

There are two Activities: `ActivityA` and `ActivityB.`

From `ActivityA` I going to `ActivityB`. Then, I choose some list item and going back to `Activity A`(same instance) with selected data. And the most difficult: if I press back now, I should going back to `ActivityB`(with same instance and with saved View state).

Is it possible to implement? Not necessary via `launchMode` attribute, perhaps there is another way to manage Activities manually via ActivityManager.

Comment: I don't know about activity manager, but i'd try overriding backPressed method and putting conditions in it, that when i have to go to Activity B and when to quit Activity A

Comment: you dont want to go back on activity when back button pressed?

Comment: That is a very unusual management of the stack and contrary to normal Android behavior, but overriding onBackPressed should work (like Sanket replied)

Answer (score 2):

In **onActivtyResult** of Activity put **boolean flag** so that you can check that it comes after selecting data from Activity B and in **onBackPressed** of **Activity A** start **Activity  B**

like this way

```
boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        flag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(flag)
        {
            //Start Activity B
        }
        else
        {
            // finish this activity
        }

    }
```

Comment: Good idea, but, I suppose, it will be a new instace of ActivityB? Without saved state?

Comment: when you start Activity B from onBackPressed at that time you can put some extra. so you can check in onCreate of activity B and you can disply previous selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult to get the result from activity B which was started by activity A. Activity B returns result when it is finished.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using it. The question is not about delivering result, the question about managing Activities in stack.